# iOS 8 - Standalone web app won't clear cache/cookies

Tags: caching, ios7, cookies, ios8, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm developing a mobile website at work that supports standalone mode when added to the home screen. Everything is working for both Android and iOS. I just upgraded my iPhone 5c to iOS 8 and whenever I open the web app from the home screen icon it has me signed in but with an account that I've used before. I click the sign out button and it works on the browser, but it doesn't seem to be clearing the cookies on standalone mode.

I tried deleting and re-adding the home screen icon, even with `?v=2` at the end but no luck. I even restarted the phone and deleted the history and data in the Safari settings.

I know there is little knowledge on iOS 8 so far, but it seems to be a bug. Any ideas?

```
$(document).on('tap', '#site-nav #sign-out', function() {       
    $.removeCookie('screen', {path: '/', domain: '.'+window.location.hostname});
    $.removeCookie('token1', {path: '/', domain: '.'+window.location.hostname});
    $.removeCookie('token2', {path: '/', domain: '.'+window.location.hostname});
    $('#site-nav').panel('close');
    Backbone.history.navigate('sign-in', {trigger: true});
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you get a solution to this as yet? I'm facing a similar issue

Comment: I know this thread is old, but we are now facing similar issue with iOS 11 and our authentication cookies hanging around after logging out and relaunching the app from home screen...see post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551996/ios-11-cookie-expiration-in-home-screen-web-apps